# How can I configure Travis CI so that `xcrun` can find `altool` (xcode 11.3 on Mac OS X 10.14)?

Tags: macos, travis-ci, xcrun, electron-notarize

When running my build for notarization on Travis CI I get the following error:

```
xcrun: error: unable to find utility “altool”, not a developer tool or in PATH
```

You can find complete build output here: https://travis-ci.org/github/trufflesuite/ganache/jobs/663747601#L3825

Complete Travis config here: https://travis-ci.org/github/trufflesuite/ganache/jobs/663747601/config

I've tried running `sudo xcode-select -r` and `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app` per [tips found on github](https://github.com/electron/electron-notarize/issues/5) and stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56617634/160173, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53204124/160173), to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have the environment variable `DEVELOPER_DIR` set somehow? Have you tried using the `-v` option to `xcrun` to get verbose output regarding its lookup logic? Have you tried using `xcrun -k` once to clear its cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that my Travis config wasn't actually using the root-level `osx_image` directive of `"xcode11.3"`; this directive was being ignored due to my use of Travis' `include` matrix. The correct way to specify the `osx_image` when using an `include` matrix is as follows:

```
matrix:
  include:
  - os: osx
    osx_image: "xcode11.3"
  - os: linux
    dist: bionic
```

Once I made this change I didn't need to try the `xcode-select` solutions linked in my question above.